# Classloading in ofbiz custom componnents

Tags: java, classloader, ofbiz

I have two custom applications, which I have deployed under the hot-deploy folder. Both these application use different versions of the same library in my case it is ZKOSS (a UI framework).

What i observe is because of the incompatibility of these 2 versions I get errors on my obbiz server startup.

I was under the impression that each application will be isolated WRT to class loading, but this does not seem to be the case. All the libraries seem to be loaded by the same class loader.

Any hints on how i can achieve this level of isolation for the custom modules i have built in ofbiz ?